# iOS/Swift: How to add 1 to i in a loop for for a specific value and how to retrograd a 'loop for' for specific moment?

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, var

I try to add 1 to i in a loop for in a specific moment? When I do this, it comes to the "normal" value instantly at the begining of the loop.

```
for var i in (0..<10)
    {
    if (i == 2)
       {
       i += 1
       }
    }
```

EDIT:

Concret code:

```
                   for var i in (0..<models.count) 
                    {
                        if (i > 0 && models[i].label1 == models[i-1].label1)
                        {
                            models[i-1].slots.append(contentsOf: models[i].slots)
                            models.remove(at: i)
                            i -= 1
                           
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Can you use ``while`` instead ``for``?

Comment: Are you saying you want to _skip_ 2? If so, say `continue`.

Comment: @matt yep exactly, I simplified the code, but what I really need is the opposite of continue. I would like to do i -= 1 (it is not so simple, because I know that it will be an infinite loop, but I simplified a lot the code for stackoverflow)

Comment: @SaketKumar I would like to retrograd the loop for certain moment. It is possible in all the langages I used, but it seems that in Swift it is not possible.

Comment: Please post the whole code and tell us what you want to achieve with that code.

Comment: I got you, everything that is possible in other language is also possible here. Let me help you with a code snippet

Comment: @SaketKumar Ok, I just put it

Comment: var i = 0
        var flag: Bool = false

        while i < 10 {
            
            if i == 2 && !flag {
                flag = true
                i += -1
                continue;
            }
            
            i += 1
        }

Does something like this solves the issue for you, once you have retracted flag becomes true, and breaks the infinite loop?

Comment: Don't post multi-line code in a comment. line breaks and formatting are lost, so it's pretty much unreadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In for loops in Swift, the variable (`i`) is treated as a let constant, and you cannot mutate it inside the loop.

That seems right. Being able to mutate a loop variable inside the loop can lead to all sorts of unexpected side-effects.

You can use a while loop to get the same effect:

The following works:

```
var i = 0
while i < 10  {
    print(i)
    if i.isMultiple(of: 2) && Int.random(in: 1...3) == 2 {
        i -= 1
    }
    i += 1
}
print("Done")
```

This code throws a compiler error:

```
for index in 1...10 {
    if index.isMultiple(of: 3) {
        index += 1 // <- Error: "left side of mutating operator isn't mutable: 'index' is a 'let' constant"
        print(index)
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok it is a pity because I already did it in other langages. While loop obliged me to change lots of things. Thank you, you confort me in what I though.

Comment: Actually, the `i` is not treated as a let constant, you can change its value, but it is scoped to the loop block, so it's forgotten before the next iteration starts.

Comment: @JeremyP I think you'll find the compiler enforces constant behaviour irrespective of scope of visibility.  Try it and you'll get an error something like `Cannot assign to value: 'i' is a 'let' constant`

Comment: @flanker, See DonMag's answer and the comments after. If you write "for **var** index in 1...10" then the compiler turns `index` into a variable inside the scope of the braces, which gets discarded after each pass. So the value of index at the beginning of each loop through the range reverts to the next enum value regardless of what you do to the var inside the braces.

Comment: @DuncanC OK, thanks for that.  Not a construct I was aware of.  Not sure it's one I'll ever find a use for though either.

Comment: @flanker, Nor was I, and it’s use seems like a code smell to me, but it’s good to know it exists at least. Props to DonMag for pointing out that detail.

Comment: @flanker I did try it myself. There are use-cases, believe it or not. One might be if you are iterating through an array of [TextOutputStream](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/textoutputstream)s and printing something to each one.

Answer (score 3):

The for loop sets the value of `i` each time through.

So,

```
    for var i in (0..<10)
    {
        // the for loop sets i to the next value in 0 to 9
        print(i)
        if (i == 2)
        {
            // print current value of i
            print("a:", i)
            i += 1
            // print current value of i
            print("b:", i)
        }
    }
```

Inside your `if (i == 2)` block, you change the value of `i` but then the for loop changes it right back to the next value in the enumeration of 0 to 9.

The debug output from the above code will look like this:

```
0
1
2
a: 2
b: 3
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

To make it more obvious, change `i += 1` to `i += 4`

Output:

```
0
1
2
a: 2
b: 6
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

---

**Edit** - *for a little more clarification...*

From the Swift Docs:

> **For-In Loops**
>
> You use the for-in loop to iterate over a sequence, such as items in an array, ranges of numbers, or characters in a string.

Both of these loops:

```
for i in 0..<3 {
    print("i =", i)
}

for i in [0, 1, 2] {
    print("i =", i)
}
```

will output this:

```
i = 0
i = 1
i = 2
```

and this loop:

```
for i in [0, 2, 4] {
    print("i =", i)
}
```

will output this:

```
i = 0
i = 2
i = 4
```

because the for-in loop is *iterating over the sequence*.

In either case, if we try to modify `i` inside the loop, we'll see this in Xcode:

[image]

If we change `i` to a var:

```
for var i in 0..<3 {
    print("a: i =", i)
    i = 7
    print("b: i =", i)
}
```

we can compile and run the code, ***but***... each time through the loop `i` will be assigned the next value in the iteration, and we'll get this:

```
a: i = 0
b: i = 7
a: i = 1
b: i = 7
a: i = 2
b: i = 7
```

As `Duncan C` explained, if we want to *actually* modify `i`, the proper thing to do is use a `while` loop.

So... why can we do *this* in other languages (such as Objective-C):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    NSLog(@"a: i = %d", i);
    i = 7;
    NSLog(@"b: i = %d", i);
}
```

and get this output:

```
a: i = 0
b: i = 7
```

and the loop exits?

That's because this:

[image]

is a more concise yet functionally equivalent way of writing this:

[image]

The Swift `For-In` loop is much more similar to the Objective-C `For-In Fast Enumeration` loop:

```
for (NSNumber *n in @[@0, @1, @2]) {
    NSLog(@"n = %@", n);
}
```

outputs:

```
n = 0
n = 1
n = 2
```

and, if we try to modify `n` inside the loop:

[image]

so we make it `__strong`:

```
for (__strong NSNumber *n in @[@0, @1, @2]) {
    NSLog(@"a: n = %@", n);
    n = @7;
    NSLog(@"b: n = %@", n);
}
```

and the output is - as you might guess:

```
a: n = 0
b: n = 7
a: n = 1
b: n = 7
a: n = 2
b: n = 7
```

Hope that helps a bit.

Comment: yes but what I would like is that the general i value change to not get the next 3... I think it is not possible in Swift langage to change the i value, in all the langages I used It was possible, but not here...

Comment: That code will not compile. You get an error: "left side of mutating operator isn't mutable: 'index' is a 'let' constant."

Comment: @ΩlostA my feeling is that the fact that most languages allow you to change a loop index inside the loop is a defect in those other languages. It is an inherently unsafe thing to do.

Comment: @DuncanC - that code compiles and runs because we say *for **var** i in 0..<10*, so `i` is no longer a `let` constant.

Comment: I didn't know you could do that. That's really the answer to the OPs question. You should emphasize that in your answer. The "for **var**" bit is the key.

Comment: @DuncanC ... see the **Edit** to my answer for some more clarification.

Comment: @ΩlostA ... see the **Edit** to my answer for some more clarification.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is caused because the `i` is scoped to the block of the loop. Each time round you actually get a new `i`.

There are three solutions.

The first is to use a `while` loop as per Duncan C's answer.

The second is to maintain a separate index and still use a for loop, but that's really just the same as the first one

The best answer IMO is to count downwards from the end.

```
for i in (1 ..< models.count).reversed()
{
    if (models[i].label1 == models[i-1].label1)
    {
        models[i-1].slots.append(contentsOf: models[i].slots)
        models.remove(at: i)
    }
}
```

Of course, reversing a list of numbers gets expensive for long lists, so you might consider using [stride](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/stride(from:to:by:))

```
for i in stride(from: models.count - 1, to: 0, by: -1)
{
    if (models[i].label1 == models[i-1].label1)
    {
        models[i-1].slots.append(contentsOf: models[i].slots)
        models.remove(at: i)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this exhaustive explanation, I understand better now